# Evaluate: $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(\int_{4x}^{5}(\int_{t}^{\sin t}\sqrt{1+u^4}du)dt)$

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem:

Evaluate $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(\int_{4x}^{5}(\int_{t}^{\sin t}\sqrt{1+u^4}du)dt)$

I have honestly no idea where to begin with this problem. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\int_{t}^{\sin{t}}\sqrt{1+u^4}du = f(t)$, so you need $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\Bigg(\dfrac{d}{dx}\bigg(\int_{4x}^{5}f(t)dt\bigg)\Bigg).$$

So using Leibniz Formula, this is equal to:
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\Bigg(-4f(4x)\Bigg) =-16f'(4x)$$

So you need $$-16\dfrac{d}{dx}\Big(\int_{4x}^{\sin{4x}}\sqrt{1+u^4}du\Big)$$

Now again using Leibniz Formula, this is equal to:
$$-16\Big(4\cos{4x}\sqrt{1+\sin^4{4x}}-4\sqrt{1+(4x)^4}\Big)$$

Therefore $$\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}\Bigg(\int_{4x}^{5}\bigg(\int_{t}^{\sin{t}}\sqrt{1+u^4}du\bigg)dt\Bigg) = -16\Big(4\cos{4x}\sqrt{1+\sin^4{4x}}-\sqrt{1+(4x)^4}\Big)$$

Comment: This may be a tough HW problem for the students, I feel..

Comment: @Dr.Sundar For a $12^{th}$ grader, probably not. It is just applying the Leibniz Integration Rule twice.

Comment: We weren't taught the Leibniz Integration Rule yet but thank you anyways

Answer (score 2):

HINT: use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule, that is, from the fundamental theorem of calculus you know that if $F(x):=\int_{a}^x f(t)\,d t$ then $\frac{d}{d x}F(x)=f(x)$. Now observe that $(F\circ g)(x)=\int_{a}^{g(x)} f(t)\,d t$, therefore $\frac{d}{d x}[(F\circ g)(x)]=\ldots $